# Matlab use fminsearch to optimize a interval of numbers

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization, integer-programming

In Matlab I want to use fminsearch to optimize a interval of numbers given a object function `fun` to minimize. The integer numbers can be selected from 1 to 30, and the number of integers is fixed to 5 for now. Assume the step size is 1. It will optimize many vectors such as:

```
[1 2 3 4 5]
[2 3 4 5 6]
[7 8 9 10 11]
[12 13 14 15 16]
```

In the long run, I may also try to optimize the step size and number of integers in the vector.

I want to know how to use fminsearch to properly realize this or maybe use other functions in the toolbox? Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm a little confused. Is it that you have this objective function `fun` that takes an interval, e.g. `1:5`, as argument and you want to find the interval that minimizes `fun`?

Comment: Your problem formulation is unclear.  why not use MILP?

Comment: @Adam I am sorry but I didn't explain it clearly. Basically, we want this optimizer can optimize other variables which is not integers later. So instead of giving it a range for searching, we want it can search through a giving list of numbers.

Comment: @SimaGuanxing When you say search through a giving list of numbers, it is like finding index of optimum in the list. It's still integer programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, as stated in [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fminsearch.html), `fminsearch` can only find minimum of unconstrained functions. [`fminbnd`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fminbnd.html), on the other hand, can handle the bound constraint, however, non of these functions are meant to solve discrete functions. So you probably want to think of other options, [`ga`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/gads/ga.html?searchHighlight=ga%20algorithm&s_tid=doc_srchtitle) for example.

Despite the fact that `fminsearch` does not handle constraints, but still you can use it to solve your optimization problem with cost of some unnecessary extra iterations. In this answer I assume that there is a `fun` function that takes an interval from a specific range as its argument and the objective is to find the interval that minimizes it.

Since the interval has a fixed step size and length, the problem is single-variable and we only need to find its start point. We can use `floor` to convert a continuous problem to a discrete one. To cover the bound constraint we can check for feasibility of intervals and return `Inf` for infeasible ones. That will be something like this:

```matlab
%% initialization of problem parameters
minval = 1;
maxval = 30;
step = 1;
count = 5;
%% the objective function
fun = @(interval) sum((interval-5).^2, 2);
%% a function that generates an interval from its initial value
getinterval = @(start) floor(start) + (0:(count-1)) * step;
%% a modified objective function that handles constraints
objective = @(start) f(start, fun, getinterval, minval, maxval);
%% finding the interval that minimizes the objective function
y = fminsearch(objective, (minval+maxval)/2);
best = getinterval(y);
eval = fun(best);
disp(best)
disp(eval)
```

where `f` function is:

```matlab
function y = f(start, fun, getinterval, minval, maxval)
interval = getinterval(start);
if (min(interval) < minval) || (max(interval) > maxval)
    y = Inf;
else
    y = fun(interval);
end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I want two constrains, say I have another variable called Vx that is from 0.1 to 0.9 with 0.1 step increase in every search, how I can accommodate the functions you write to realize it? Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @SimaGuanxing In that case `start` would be a vector and you need to fix their steps and check their validity independently. It's like `Vx=floor(start(2) * 10)/10; if (Vx<0.1) || (Vx>0.9) y=Inf;.

Comment: I sort of understand what you suggest to change but still confused when I implement it. Should I use the same f function for different variables or use same function? I would be really appreciated if you can update the code to reflect the change for the second constrains. Thanks!

Comment: Implement it in same function. `fminsearch` is capable of minimizing multivariate functions. So when you call fminsearch(X, Y), X and Y can both be vectors of same size. Now, when you want to check for feasibility of a solution, you need to check all of its variables.

Comment: @SimaGuanxing I really think that you need to ask a new question about multivariate functions using `fminsearch`. And try to describe what you have done, and what the problem is.

Comment: Okay. I will try to implement it first and open a new thread for multivariate functions using fminsearch if needed. Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202921/discussion-between-simaguanxing-and-saastn).

Comment: I created a new thread for this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59002429/matlab-use-fminsearch-to-optimize-multi-variables